# Hamming code of length $8$ self dual

Tags: linear-algebra, information-theory, coding-theory

I'm reading a paper by N.J.A Sloane on self dual codes, and he introduces the binary Hamming code of length $8$ with generator matrix  $$ G = \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&1&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&0&1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where if we assign labels to the columns from left to right; $\infty, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6$, then the second row has $1's$ where the column is labelled by a quadratic residue mod $7$. Then we cyclic shift to get the remaining rows.

What is being done here? I assume we just ignore the first row and first column as this just extends the matrix. I've looked in to quadratic residue codes but I can't seem to find the link between them and this generator matrix? Could anyone explain what's being done here?

The paper I'm referring to can be found here; https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612535.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quadratic residue (QR) code of length $p$
over the finite field $GF(m)$ whenever $p$
and $m$ are primes, $p$ is odd, and 
$m$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

It just happens that the (7,4,3) Hamming Code, and the (23,12,7) Golay Code, both over $GF(2)$ (thus $m=2$)
can also be expressed as QR codes.

As $p$ increases, QR codes are no longer very efficient, with their minimum distance asymptotically $O(\sqrt{p})$ but for short lengths they produce the above two perfect codes.

**Edit:** The online magma calculator is quite useful for computations in coding theory. You can access it [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/).

Entering

> QRCode(GF(2),7); HammingCode(GF(2),3);

gives

> [7, 4, 3] "Quadratic Residue code" Linear Code over GF(2)

and

> [7, 4, 3] "Hamming code (r = 3)" Linear Code over GF(2)

and displays the same generator matrix for both.

Comment: Isn’t the matrix above a generator matrix for a code of length $7$ and dimension $3$ though? So not the $(7,4,3)$ Hamming code?

Comment: Yes, the QR code and e Hamming code councide in this case.

Comment: But the generator matrix above has $3$ rows and thus has dimension $3$ right? So how is it the $(7,4,3)$ code which has dimension $4$?

Comment: No, it doesnt. Did you run the command?

Comment: I mean when we delete the first column and first row, we get a $ 3 \times 7$ matrix right? So isn’t it the generator matrix for the dual of the Hamming $(7,4,3)$ code?

Answer (score 0):

The code is self-dual. The generator matrix is also the parity check matrix. If you consider the matrix $G$ as parity check matrix, then deleting the first row and the first column gives the parity check matrix of the 7,4,3 Hamming code.

Comment: Thank you. What does this have to do with the quadratic residues, though?